# Evaluating buffer until the cursor

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I am trying to create a key binding for "Evaluate buffer till here" in Emacs & ESS, which is situated in ESS => ESS Eval menu. Most of the commands in that menu are listed in help files (http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html, and in Emacs options), but this particular one is not. If I place following code in .emacs file:

```
(eval-after-load "ess-mode" '(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "C-.") 'ess-eval-buffer-till-here))
```

I get a following message when trying to use the binding: `Symbol´s function definition is void: ess-eval-buffer-till-here`. Obviously I am calling for wrong name. What is the right name for this command and how can I see *all* of the commands for ESS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it's a menu item? Type <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> and then select that item.

(Menus are implemented as keymaps, so this is just the normal `describe-key` functionality.)

You can also see the non-interactive call form of the last command with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd> or <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>M-:</kbd>.  It's easy to figure out the command name once you have that. *(thanks event_jr)*

For listing all commands, most modes will list all their key bindings in their docstring, so you can use <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> to describe the modes in use in the buffer.

As there may be commands without bindings, you could also use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `apropos-command` to list them all (most likely specifying `^ess` as a pattern, if it uses that as a consistent name space).

Comment: No problem :) (I trust the site does at least warn you when that happens?)

Comment: Nice! The command is called `ess-eval-buffer-from-beg-to-here`, so `(eval-after-load "ess-mode" '(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "C-.") 'ess-eval-buffer-from-beg-to-here))` works. Thanks!

Comment: @phils didn't warn me this time, may be a bug.